# In go, is this line creating a new empty map with string as key and value?

Tags: go

```
keys := []string{}
```

In go, is this line creating a new empty map with string as key and value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's creating an empty string slice.

This is an empty map with string as key and value:

```
keys := map[string]string{}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what is the type, you can always check using [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
     keys := []string{}
     fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(keys))
     fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(keys).Elem())
}
```

Output:

```
[]string
string
```

Which means an empty slice of string.

Another eg to check the types inside the slice:

```
keys := []string{}
anotherKeys := []map[string]string{}

fmt.Println("keys: ", reflect.TypeOf(keys).Elem())
fmt.Println("anotherKeys: ", reflect.TypeOf(anotherKeys).Elem())
```

Output:

```
keys: string
anotherKeys: map[string]string
```

NB:
[Elem()](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem)

Answer (score 0):

No, `[]string` is a slice of strings.

If you want an empty map with strings as the type for both keys and values, then `map[string]string` would be the correct type. [Try the following example code in the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mukBMTGc2Y) to see it for yourself:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func printKind(i interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("Kind of %#v: %s\n", i, reflect.TypeOf(i).Kind())
}

func main() {
    emptySlice := []string{}
    printKind(emptySlice)

    emptyMap := map[string]string{}
    printKind(emptyMap)
}
```